# Will self-signed server certificates expiration date matter if I already imported it to client's truststore

Tags: ssl, certificate, client, ssl-certificate, server

I guess the question is very self-explanatory. I have a self-signed certificate on the server, and it's imported to my client's truststore (Client and Server is all java based). I wonder if the certificate expires, will the client still honor that certificate and not cease trusting it? In short, will the client still be able to connect after the certificate expired?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no, since the code was signed using a certificate that sooner or later will expire.

Using a CA code signing cert (example: DigiCert.com) will maintain the signed files valid for life when adding "timestamp" to sign the jar file(s). Any OS or browser will automatically trust the source (your organization) because a  valid CA issued it (DigiCert). The pre-loaded root certs link to the code signing cert even after the code signing order expired. CA's will update their Root Certs a few years before it expires.

Comment: I don't think this is about code signing, it's about SSL/TLS. There are also two distinct questions (is your answer "no" to the title question or the question in the last paragraph?)

Comment: @Bruno Yeah, you are right. Sorry!

But the answer is almost the same. The client is going to require a new valid self signed cert to visit the site each time it expires

Answer (score 1):

> In short, will the client still be able to connect after the certificate expired?

No, it won't. Adding a certificate as a trust anchor (i.e. in your trust store) doesn't bypass name verification (assuming it's turned on in the first place) or date validation.